# VLCJ (JAVA) in the Same Jframe

Tags: java, swing

I made a sample application with **java/java swing**. I use **VLCJ** to read some video, my problem is that I need to know about how I can embed the video in the main frame (same jframe).
Can someone help me, because I tried over and over and found no solution.

[image]

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setLocation(100,100);
    f.setSize(640,360);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);

    Canvas c = new Canvas();
    c.setBackground(Color.black);
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(c);
    f.add(p);
    
    NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(),"C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC");
    Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);
    MediaPlayerFactory mpf = new MediaPlayerFactory();
    
    EmbeddedMediaPlayer emp = mpf.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer(new Win32FullScreenStrategy(f));
    emp.setVideoSurface(mpf.newVideoSurface(c));
    
    String file = "link of video";
    emp.prepareMedia(file);
    
    emp.play();
```

Comment: It looks to me like it is working correctly - you create a frame, add a video surface and it plays the video in *that* frame. If you want to embed the video in your *other* frame, well, set the video surface to be a Canvas that added to the *other* frame. If you do f.setTitle("whatever") you will see it's the wrong frame.

Comment: do you have exemple how can i embed in jpanel without frame and thx

Comment: Add the Canvas you're using for the video surface to the JPanel in your other frame. That's it.

Comment: i make my code it work but i can't make it the same frame if you have discord or facebook i will make for you video to look at it